# PHP: How to compare 2 Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, compare, conditional-statements

I've two Arrays and would like to check, if there's any difference in it's values. I've two solutions (below) but I think there should be a better way I don't know.

**Data**

```
$old_data = array(
    "name" => "Mister X",
    "age" => 43
);

$new_data = array(
    "name" => "Mister X",
    "age" => 44
);
```

**Solution A**

Doesn't work, if an Integer is formatted like a String: 44 vs. "44". Also encoding the Array seems dirty for me.

```
if (json_encode($old_data) != json_encode($new_data)) {
    echo "there's a difference.";
}
```

**Solution B**

Build two Strings of the Arrays' values and compare them.

```
function array_values_to_string($array) {
    $str = "";
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $str .= $value;
    }
    return $str;
}

if (array_values_to_string($array_old) != array_values_to_string($array_new)) {
    echo "there's a difference.";
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using array_diff()? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for your quick reply. That's what I forgot and needed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use https://www.php.net/array_diff

```
<?php
$old_data = array(
  "name" => "Mister X",
  "age" => 43
);

$new_data = array(
  "name" => "Mister X",
  "age" => 44
);

print_r(array_diff($old_data, $new_data));
?>
```

This will output :

```
Array ( [age] => 43 )
```